Matrix optimization via setting column maximums
I wish to perform the following optimization on a matrix of positive integers with the following constraints:

The row sums cannot exceed a set value $S$.
we may set the maximum value of a column $Aj$ as $M_j$. Doing so incurs the following loss: if $A_{ij} > M_j$, we say we have lost $A_{ij} -M_j$

The goal is to choose values for $M_j$ so that $$\sum A_{ij} - M_j$$ is minimized.
A naive approach would be to set ALL the maximums as something obvious, like $S/(number col)$, but then we risk “losing” where we don’t have to.
Any other approaches to this are appreciated!

It is unclear what you want to do. As I understand it, you want to minimize the sum of the coefficients in the rows. If $(m,n)$ is the size of $A$, just add another variable $M$ and $m$ constraints $\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} \leq M$, $i=1,\dots,m$. Minimize $M$.

The only “operation” that’s allowed to happen is “replacing” the large values in a column with a chosen maximum $M_j$, where $A_{ij} \leftarrow min(M_{j}, A_{ij})$ at the cost of the difference. Can you elaborate further? I can give a numerical example if necessary

Well, if $M_j$ is the maximum of the coefficients in the $j$th column of $A$, how can $A_{ij} > M_j$ ever holds? Also, in $\sum A_{ij} - M_j$, what are you summing over? My guess is over the index $i$, but then, you have $n$ values. Are you trying to do some kind of multi objective optimisation?

The $M_j$ is imposed after A is given. I.e. someone hands you a matrix A and max row sum S, and you may choose $M_j$ however you like to satisfy the condition.

The sum is taken over All i,j.

So your only decision variables are $M_j$? But still $M_j  = \max_i A_{ij}$, $\forall j$? If this is the case, there is nothing to do.

No, you may set $M_j$ however you want

OK, as I understand it, here is how I would formulate your problem:
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
  \min_{M_j,t_{ij}} & \sum_{i,j} t_{ij} \\
   s.t. & \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
     A_{ij}-M_j \leq t_{ij} & ,\ i=1,\dots,m,\ j=1,\dots,n \\
     t_{ij} \geq 0  & ,\ i=1,\dots,m,\ j=1,\dots,n \\
\sum_j M_j \leq S
     \end{array} \right.
\end{array}
$$
